# The boundedness of a solution to differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the system
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt}&=aux(1-x)-b(1-u)x\tag{1}\\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=b(1-u)x-\eta_1 y\tag{2}\\
\frac{dz}{dt}&=k_1x+k_2y-\eta_2z-\alpha_1zw\tag{3}\\
\frac{dw}{dt}&=w(1-w)-\alpha_2zw\tag{4}
\end{align}

we want to show that if the initial conditions are non negative, then the solutions are bounded.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJiwN.jpg) is the proof which I don't understand.

My question is: how is that the second equality in the proof hold?(I tried to expand the second equation but I didn't get the first equation) here what I get
$$aux(1-x)-\eta_1y+\underbrace{(1-au)\biggl(\frac{\eta_1^2}{4au}+\frac{\eta_1}{2}+\frac{au}{4}\biggl)}_{\mbox{extra}}$$

And finally what "standard differential inequalities" do we use to show
$$x+y\leq \frac{(\eta_1+au)^2}{4au\eta_1}$$
*Any clarification is appreciated!*

Comment: What is $w$ and what is $u$? Is $w=w(t)$ a function of $t$ and $u$ a constant or is it a typo and $w(t)=u(t)$? Otherwise the identity is correct and the inequality is a version of Gronwall's inequality. Just google it.